# Error en Batch para busqueda de texto en .txt

Tags: batch

alguien me pudiera apoyar con el siguiente código, ya que no logro ejecutar en varios archivos mediante un .bat :

```
@echo off

set /p serial = Escribe el Serial:

set /a serial = (%serial%)
echo.

findstr /i /m /l /C:"%serial%" \\server\Resultados\*.txt >> c:\lista.txt
color 60
PAUSE
```

Answer (score 0):

Para introducir una cadena en una variable, debes concatenar la variable con el simbolo `=` y el valor que indica  la cadena a introducir, de esta forma:

```
set /p variable=cadena
```

si los separas no funcionará correctamente.

Esta sería la forma de buscar la palabra definida en `serial`, en todos los archivos con extensión .txt contenidos en `\\server\Resultados\`, los resultados los guardara en el archivo `c:\lista.txt` :

```
@echo off

set /p serial=Escribe el Serial:
echo buscando: %serial%!
echo.

findstr /i "%serial%" \\server\Resultados\*.txt >> c:\lista.txt

color 60
PAUSE
```

Comment: Excelente Jorgesys. Funciona a la perfección, muchas gracias.

Comment: Exclente Victorino, te recomiendo revisar cada uno de los modificadores de findstr y su uso para que te sea más sencillo realizar una tarea con un bat, saludos!.